# Database Needs Relation

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

In Microsoft Retail Management System, if we examine the database , it did not use any one of the following relation:

One to One

One to Many

Many to Many

one expert said me that , sometime relations are harmful same as it is harmful in our daily life. So avoid relation in both in life and database. I still considered it as a joke.

so, please tell me, whats is the really need to use relations even same thing we can also manage by query etc.

Comment: By relations, you mean the employment of foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Relationships (ER Model) are good because they describe your model - simply said you can more easily see which Entities are related to each other when on the diagram they are connected to each other.

As for if relationship should have a foreign key (Storage Model), then the answer is: It depends.

It depends on what is the nature of relationship. In the company I work for we follow the rule: 
Create FK only between entities defined by user (for relationships that are meaningful to him, like Customer - Order), avoid FK on entities that are automatically added by the system (like log/audit entries, especially if there are many of them).

If you have a foreign key, this can impact performance when deleting entities because the database has to check if this entity isn't "in use". This takes as much time as performing appropriate `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

[relational-database](/questions/tagged/relational-database)s and [entity-relationship](/questions/tagged/entity-relationship)s have very little at all to do with each other.

A relational database is composed of one or more sets of facts, organized into relations.  In this model, a relation is nothing more than a bunch of facts that make the same "kind" of claim.  In order to make sure that the set of facts represented in the database are valid, there are usually some additional constraints applied to the way facts can be represented.  First, facts have to be identifiable, there should be a "key" for each fact, and only one such fact for any possible key.  The other is that when one fact makes a claim about another fact, it must definitely be that the fact claimed about (the referant) exists and agrees with the "meta-fact".

As an example of the above, you certainly never want to be in a position where you know "customer 10 is 15 days behind on his payments", but that you don't know which customer 10 is the one that's behind, because there's more than one of them, or that there's no customer 10 at all.  These constraints serve to force the database to be "consistent".

---

entity relationships, on the other hand, are only meaningful in terms of application design.  It's a "language" to describe how abstract program components relate to each other.  Relational databases provide, by way of functional dependence, a way of modeling this "is-a", "has-many", "belongs-to" kind of design, but it is by no means the only one.  Another example is inheritance and composition used in object oriented design.

Significantly, an application may have several classes, which are sufficiently independent of one another that no composition or inheritance is needed, and similarly, an database may have no functional dependencies, but will still be consistent.

That said, such applications will probably be both small and uncommon; these tools provide some significant value to the task of designing a "good" application, and virtually all will make some, and possibly extensive use of these tools.